# passing an object from controller and using it in jquery

Tags: jquery, arrays

I have a controller and I am passing a array list to jsp page using model and view.Now I need this array list to be used in a java script function.

my jsp page is:

`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#click").click(function(){
      var y=$("#hid").val();
      for (var key in y) {
          alert(y[key].location);
        }

    });
});
</script>
<input type="hidden" id="hid" value="${cabsList}" />
```

`

and my controller is

```
public ModelAndView userHomePage() {
        Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        ArrayList<Driver> list = driverService.retriveDriverList();
        model.put("cabsList", list);
        return new ModelAndView("userHome",model);
    }
```

So i need to use that cabsList  in my jquery function.cabs list contains details of the cabs.I need to access their location to finish that jquery function

Comment: The issue your most likely running into is that your treating the value of #hid as an array.  But as far as html is concerned, it's a string.  You'll have to do some parsing yourself to get it to be an array.

Comment: i got that but now Iam not able to iterate over that list of objects

Comment: Magus below had a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

When you do `${cabsList}`, the `toString` method will be used. Since `cabsList` is an `ArrayList`, the result will be something like `[firstElement, secondElement, ...]`.

So when you do `var y=$("#hid").val();`, `y` will contains a string with this value. You can't really use it like an array or an object.

My advice :

- Change your controller to put a real string in your model. Something like `firstDriver,secondDriver,...`
- In your javascript code, use `var y=$("#hid").val().split(',');` to read your values